# implement multiple conditions in where clause C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, listbox-control

**situation** : i have a event handler of a search textbox in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    void src_textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

        listBoxTextItems.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.Problems.Where(w => w.ProblemName.ToLower().Contains(tb.Text));

    }
```

listBoxTextItems : name of listbox control ,
Problems : name of collection instantiated in MainViewModelClass constructor ,

this code shows only those objects whose `ProblemName` property contains the letters typed in textbox .

**Problem** : what i want is that this code should also show those objects whose `ProblemDesc` property contains the letters typed in textbox .

i tried something like this :

```
            listBoxTextItems.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.Problems.Where((w => w.ProblemName.ToLower().Contains(tb.Text))||(w => w.ProblemDesc.ToLower().Contains(tb.Text)));
```

but i get an error saying "operator `||` cannot be applied to operands of type `lambda expression` and `lambda expression`. can anyone suggest me correct code ?

Comment: Instead of `(w => w.X) || (w => w.Y)` which is illegal you want `w => (w.X || w.Y)` and you can omit the parenthesis. Another option (that I don't like) is to have **two** `Where`s, so `.Where(w => w.X).Where(w => w.Y)`. Edit: Oops, two `Where`s work like `&&` of course, not like `||`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify lambda parameter whenever you need to use it. Just specify it once:

```
App.ViewModel.Problems.Where(w => w.ProblemName.ToLower().Contains(tb.Text) || 
                                  w.ProblemDesc.ToLower().Contains(tb.Text));
```

When you specify `w` second time, you are creating a new lambda expression therefore you get the error.Simple syntax of lambda expression is:

```
(input parameters) => expression
```

In this case you have only one input parameter which is `w`, you need to specify it only once so you will be using the same parameter and create only one *lambda expression* which returns a boolen result.

You can refer to documentation for more detailed explanation about lambda expressions:

- [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What's the point of an answer that's exactly the same as two here already..?

Comment: @DavidSpence **explanation**

Comment: @Selman22 I'd upvote if you write a **good** explanation. I think this would explain nothing to someone who doesn't understand lambdas very well. It could also be misleading. But that's just my opinion. :)

Comment: @yasen I hope it is better now :)

Comment: @Selman22 Now that's the kind of answer I like to see in SO! +1 and good job. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there...

```
listBoxTextItems.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.Problems.Where(w => w.ProblemName.ToLower().Contains(tb.Text) || w.ProblemDesc.ToLower().Contains(tb.Text));
```